# Cast an iterator to another type

Tags: c++, arrays, architecture, vector

I'm working on a renderer using OpenGL.

**I've got a first class, Geometry:**

```
class Geometry
{
 public:

    void setIndices( const unsigned int* indices, int indicesCount );

 private:
    std::vector<unsigned char> colors;
    std::vector<float>         positions;
    std::vector<unsigned int>  indices;
};
```

Sometimes, my geometries need to stock for his indices with different type, data can be:

```
1. std::vector<unsigned char> 
2. std::vector<short> 
3. std::vector<int>

// I've already think about std::vector<void>, but it sound dirty :/.
```

Currently, I use **unsigned int** everywhere and I cast my data when I want to set it to my geometry:

```
const char* indices = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
geometry.setIndices( (const unsigned int*) indices, 4 );
```

Later, I would like to update or read this array during runtime (array can stock more than 60000 indices sometimes), so I do something like that:

```
std::vector<unsigned int>* indices = geometry.getIndices();
indices->resize(newIndicesCount);

std::vector<unsigned int>::iterator it = indices->begin();
```

The problem is that my iterator loop on a **unsigned int** array, so iterator goto 4 bytes to 4 bytes, my initial data can be char (so 1 byte to 1 byte). It's impossible to read my initial data or update it with new data.

When I want update my vector, my only solution is to create a new array, fill it with data, then cast it to an unsigned int array, I would like to iterate on my indices pointer.

1. **How can I do something generic (working with unsigned int, char and short)?**
2. **How can I iterate over the array without copy?**

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Seems your problem is the cast when you call `setIndices()`, not when working with the vector iterators!

Answer (score 2):

Casting to the wrong pointer type would give undefined behaviour and will certainly fail if, as here, the type has the wrong size.

> How can I do something generic (working with unsigned int, char and short)?

A template would be the simplest way to make that generic:

```
template <typename InputIterator>
void setIndices(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end) {
    indices.assign(begin, end);
}
```

Usage (correcting your example to use an array rather than a pointer):

```
const char indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
geometry.setIndices(std::begin(indices), std::end(indices));
```

You might consider a convenience overload to take containers, arrays and other range types directly:

```
template <typename Range>
void setIndices(Range const & range) {
    setIndices(std::begin(range), std::end(range));
}

const char indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
geometry.setIndices(indices);
```

> How can I iterate over the array without copy?

You can't change the type of an array without copying the data. To avoid a copy, you'll have to expect the correct array type.

Comment: Thanks! But I can't do that because my type become "int", so when I send my indices to OpenGL, type is wrong so primitive isn't draw. (my unsigned char become unsigned int) :/